# How do I load a classpath resource from tomcat's lib directory?

Tags: java, servlets, classpath

I know how to do this with Spring using ClassPathResource. However, I don't want to include Spring just for something that simple. How do get a resource under Tomcat's lib directory using the standard JavaSE or Java servlet API?

Comment: Do you mean, from one of the JAR's in tomcat/lib directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Class.getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).